# How to use EasyMock to test a "tree of calls" when all nodes are mocks?

Tags: java, easymock

Suppose that I have three types: `TopHandler`, `HandlerA`, and `HandlerB`. 
Each of them has a `void handle(Something)` method.

An instance of `TopHandler` holds references to instances of `HandlerA` and `HandlerB`, and it  invokes `handle()` on `HandlerA` and `HandlerB`.

In my test I want to mock all three objects, and then verify that the invocation on topHandler would cause the invocation on the other two.

How do I specify that? I know that EasyMock lets me specify the expected behavior of the mocks, but I wasn't clear what features to use here.

Answer (score 3):

According to the OP's description, the main interface which is mocked is the `Handler` interface:

```
public interface Handler {
    void handle(String o);
}
```

All three mocked objects shall implement this interface and the TopHandler class is the class under test:

```
public static class TopHandler implements Handler {
    private Handler a;
    private Handler b;
    public TopHandler(Handler a, Handler b) {
        this.a = a; this.b = b;
    }
    public void handle(String o) {
        a.handle(o);
        b.handle(o);
    }
}
```

The test case must verify that the `TopHandler` implementation indeed calls the `handle()` method of a and b:

```
@Test
public void testTopHandler() throws Exception {
    Handler mockA = EasyMock.createMock(Handler.class);
    mockA.handle("Test");
    EasyMock.expectLastCall().once();

    Handler mockB = EasyMock.createMock(Handler.class);
    mockB.handle("Test");
    EasyMock.expectLastCall().once();

    TopHandler handler = new TopHandler(mockA, mockB);
    EasyMock.replay(mockA, mockB);
    handler.handle("Test");
    EasyMock.verify(mockA, mockB);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to mock TopHandler as that seems to be the class you are actually testing. In your test case, mock the other two as normal and check that they were called. If you mock all of your classes, there is nothing to test.

If you actually have a another class being tested that calls TopHandler then you only need to verify that this is called in the test case, as the other calls are a test for TopHandler only.